# Redux RTK req body not seen by the services

Tags: node.js, redux, react-redux

Im experimenting with Redux's RTK building a little Pokemon app.

In the app I want to add a pokemon to my pokedex by sending the `pokemonID` to an endpoint using `"POST" method`. When I use RTK, I can see the network payload just fine, but on the services the `req.body` is empty.

If I do the complete same in Thunder Client it works just fine...

I have no idea why the `pokemonId` is lost in the `req.body` with RTK...

Payload:

```
{pokemonId: 2}
```

Usage:

```
    const [addToPokedex, { isLoading }] = useAddToPokedexMutation();

    function handleClick() {
        addToPokedex(pokemon.id);
    }
```

RTK PokeAPI:

```
export const pokedexApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'pokedex',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: `${endpoint}`,
        prepareHeaders(headers) {
            headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", react_app_domain);
            headers.set("Authorization", cookies.get('Authorization'));
            return headers;
        }
    }),
    tagTypes: ['pokedex'],
    endpoints(builder) {
        return {
            fetchPokedex: builder.query<PokemonApiResponse, void>({
                query() {
                    return '/list'
                },
                providesTags: ["pokedex"]
            }),
            addToPokedex: builder.mutation<PokemonApiResponse, number>({
                query: pokemonId => ({
                    url: '/catch',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ pokemonId })
                }),
                invalidatesTags: ["pokedex"]
            }),
            removeFromPokedex: builder.mutation<PokemonApiResponse, number>({
                query: pokemonId => ({
                    url: `/release/${pokemonId}`,
                    method: 'DELETE',
                }),
                invalidatesTags: ["pokedex"]
            })
        }
    }
})


export const {
    useFetchPokedexQuery,
    useAddToPokedexMutation,
    useRemoveFromPokedexMutation
} = pokedexApiSlice;
```

The endpoint controller:

```
export const addToPokedex = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<PokedexResponse> => {

    const { pokemonId } = req.body;
    const { userId } = res.locals;

    console.log("CATCH!")
    console.log(req.body)

    try {

        const pokedex: Pokedex = await PokedexModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { userId: userId },
            { $push: { pokemons: pokemonId } },
            { new: true, upsert: true }
        );

        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            pokemons: pokedex.pokemons || []
        })
    }
    catch (err: any) {
        return res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.message,
            pokemons: []
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the `body` to a simple object. No `JSON.stringify()` is needed.

Unfortunately it does not throw any errors when utilizing `JSON.stringify()`...

```
  addToPokedex: builder.mutation<PokemonApiResponse, number>({
                query: pokemonId => ({
                    url: '/catch',
                    method: 'POST',
--                  body: JSON.stringify({ pokemonId })
++                  body: { pokemonId }
                }),
                invalidatesTags: ["pokedex"]
            }),
```